# Which answers are correct among five expressions? or have the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

A: I think she has had plastic surgery.

B: Yes. She definitely is not a natural beauty.

Yes. She definitely is not the natural beauty.

Yes. She definitely is not in natural beauty.

Yes. She definitely is not in a natural beauty.

Yes. She definitely is not in the natural beauty.

;thanks in advance

Comment: This type of question would be much more appropriate on [ell.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no context, this is the correct answer:

> Yes. She definitely is not a natural beauty.

The next answer, "Yes. She definitely is not the natural beauty." would be correct if this woman was among a group in which there was exactly one 'natural beauty.'

The constructions using 'in' construe 'natural beauty' as a location, which is incorrect in all but the most contrived situations.

Comment: _in_ is not always used to convey location, e.g. _in color_.

Comment: True, there are many uses for 'in.' The explanation was meant only to clarify why the 'in' constructions were incorrect.